# Displaying Opencv.js Matrix without cv.imshow()

Tags: javascript, arrays, opencv, matrix

Hello Stack Overflow community.

I am attempting to extract the pixel values from a cropped section of an opencv matrix to a javascript array in order to feed that data into a tensor for OCR.  I cannot use `cv.imshow()` because it interacts with the DOM and my process is on a web worker.

This is what I have so far to convert from Opencv to js array:

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
let rect = new cv.Rect(100, 100, 300, 300);
dst = src.roi(rect);

// equivalent(ish) to cv.imshow();
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOutput');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

let imageData = context.createImageData(dst.cols, dst.rows);
imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(dst.data, dst.cols, dst.rows));

canvas.height = dst.rows;
canvas.width = dst.cols;

context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
// end cv.imshow()

src.delete();
dst.delete();
```

If you paste this code into [Opencv IDE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.9/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html) and click **try it** the output seems to be offsetting weirdly.  What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Maybe that OpenCV for Node.js documentation could help you? https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/de6/tutorial_js_nodejs.html
Also you could try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp to avoid dealing with the canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should help you:

```
let mat = new cv.Mat();
// Initialise a MatVector
let matVec = new cv.MatVector();
// Push a Mat back into MatVector
matVec.push_back(mat);
// Get a Mat fom MatVector
let cnt = matVec.get(0);
mat.delete(); matVec.delete(); cnt.delete();
```

Refer the opencv.js documentation [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html) for more details.